# show carousel items dynamically

Tags: reactjs, list, modal-dialog, carousel

I have a modal with the following return value:

```
          return(  
           <Modal show={opened} centered onHide={close}>
             <Modal.Header id="savedCloset" closeButton>
                <Modal.Title>Nice title</Modal.Title>
             </Modal.Header>
             <Modal.Body>
                <Carousel cols={1} rows={1} loop>
                    <Carousel.Item>
                        <Card sx={{ maxWidth: 1000 }}>
                            {dataC[0] === undefined ? "" : <CardMedia component="img" width="1000" height="300" image={dataC[0].UP_IMAGEPATH} alt="" title={dataC[0].UP_IMAGEPATH} /> }
                            <CardContent>
                                <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="div">
                                    {dataC[0] === undefined ? "" : <> {dataC[0].UP_DATE} - {dataC[0].UP_PRICE} euro </> }
                                </Typography>
                            </CardContent>
                            <CardActions>
                                <Button onClick={editCloset}>Edit <FaEdit/></Button>
                                <Button onClick={deleteCloset}>Delete <FaTrashAlt/></Button>
                                <Button onClick={() => alert("Settings page")}>Pay <FaShoppingCart/></Button>
                            </CardActions>
                        </Card>                    
                    </Carousel.Item>
                </Carousel>
             </Modal.Body>
          </Modal>
        )
```

It works good, but like you can see, it only gives me back the data of the first record: dataC[0].UP_IMAGEPATH, dataC[0].UP_DATE, ...
I want to loop throu the records and I wrote this:

```
          return(
          <Modal show={opened} centered onHide={close}>
            <Modal.Header id="savedCloset" closeButton>
                <Modal.Title>Nice title</Modal.Title>
            </Modal.Header>
            <Modal.Body>
                <Carousel cols={1} rows={1} loop>
                    {[dataC].map(ddd => {
                    return(    
                    <Carousel.Item>
                    <Card sx={{ maxWidth: 1000 }}>
                        {ddd === undefined ? "" : <CardMedia component="img" width="1000" height="300" image={ddd.UP_IMAGEPATH} alt="" title={ddd.UP_IMAGEPATH} /> }
                        <CardContent>
                            <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="div">
                                {ddd === undefined ? "" : <> {ddd.UP_DATE} - {ddd.UP_PRICE} euro </> }
                            </Typography>
                        </CardContent>
                        <CardActions>
                            <Button onClick={editCloset}>Edit <FaEdit/></Button>
                            <Button onClick={deleteCloset}>Delete <FaTrashAlt/></Button>
                            <Button onClick={() => alert("Settings page")}>Pay <FaShoppingCart/></Button>
                        </CardActions>
                    </Card>                    
                    </Carousel.Item>
                    )
                    })}
                </Carousel>
            </Modal.Body>
          </Modal>
        )
```

This doesn't work, it shows nothing. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I call the map function like this:

> [dataC].map(ddd => {

I put [] around dataC because otherwise it gives me the error TypeError: dataC.map is not a function.

But dataC is for 100% an array. It contains:

> [{"UP_ID":1,"UP_USER_ID":2,"UP_PRICE":"1236.83","UP_DATE":"2023-03-13"},{"UP_ID":3,"UP_USER_ID":2,"UP_PRICE":"911.96","UP_DATE":"2023-03-22"}]

This dataC comes back from the database from a select statement. I have to remove the [] but than I get the other error.